# Casting Warning in C : assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to take input from a user and I don't the exact length of input so therefore I am using malloc and I am splitting char by space between them and just need to print an array but I am getting warning i.e assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast on the following line:

```
array[i++] = p;
```

and my whole program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  char buf[] ="abc qwe ccd";
  int i;
  char *p;
  char *array=malloc(sizeof(char));
  i = 0;
  p = strtok (buf," ");
  while (p != NULL)
  {
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  for (i=0;i<3; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assignment is not right.

```
array[i++] = p;
```

`array[i++]` evaluates to type `char`. `p` is of type `char*`.

That's what the compiler is complaining about. 
Judging by the way you are using `array`, it needs to be of type `char**`.

```
char **array = malloc(sizeof(*array)*20); // Make it large enough for your needs.
```

Comment: Thanx alot. Pointers always kill me :(

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER, you are welcome. It takes a bit getting used to.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you wanted to create array of pointers to `char` instead of array of `char`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char buf[] ="abc qwe ccd";
  int i;
  char *p;
  /* change type of array from char* to char** */
  char **array=malloc(sizeof(char*) * sizeof(buf)); /* allocate enough memory */
  i = 0;
  p = strtok (buf," ");
  while (p != NULL)
  {
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  for (i=0;i<3; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
  free(array); /* it is good to free whatever you allocated */
  return 0;
}
```